# Cluster Rows in Data Subgroups

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I have a dataset `df` of object components in 3-d space - each `ID` represents an object which has various components:

```
ID   Comp   x        y        z
A    1      2        2        1     
A    2      2        1        -1
A    3      -10      1        -10
A    4      -1       3        -5
B    1      3        0        0
B    2      3        0        -5
...
```

I would like to loop through each `ID`, using a clustering technique in `sklearn` to create clusters of components (`Comp`) based on each component's (`x`,`y`,`z`) co-ordinates - to achieve something like this:

```
ID   Comp   x        y        z        cluster
A    1      2        2        1        1
A    2      2        1        -1       1
A    3      -10      1        -10      2
A    4      -1       3        -5       3
B    1      3        0        0        1
B    2      3        0        -5       1
...
```

As an example - `ID`:`A,`Comp`:1 is in`cluster`1, whereas`ID`:`A, `Comp`:4 is in `cluster` 3. *(I plan to then concatenate `ID` and `cluster` later).*

I'm having no luck with the following `groupby + apply`:

```py
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation
ap = AffinityPropagation()

df['cluster']=df.groupby(['ID','Comp']).apply(lambda x: ap.fit_predict(np.array([x.x,x.y,x.z]).T))
```

I could brute-force it by using a `for` loop over the `ID` but my dataset is large (~ 150k `ID`) and I'm worried about resource and time constraints. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, I think you could try something like this:

```
def ap_fit_pred(x):
    ap = AffinityPropagation()
    return pd.Series(ap.fit_predict(x.loc[:,['x','y','z']]))

df['cluster'] = df.groupby('ID').apply(ap_fit_pred).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: I edited my post for more clarity, but will give this a go - thanks!

Comment: The code above generated a column called `cluster` filled with `Na`. I managed to (clumsily) solve that by changing the index of the dataset and using `level` in the `reset_index`. +1 for getting me 95% of the way there!